# Match-Merging Causing Concatenated Data

Tags: sas

I am trying to match merge two data sets by the variable "country". Both data sets contain the variable country (one has it named as "name" but was changed to country) and other variables, one data set (data1) contains continent information. However, I run into the issue of SAS just concatenating the data sets, that is, stacking them on top of one another.

I have tried the basics, sorting the data sets by the same by variables and making sure to use the by statement when merging the data sets.

```
proc sort data=data1;
by name;
run;

proc sort data=data2;
by country;
run;

data merged_data;
length continent $ 20 country $ 200;
merge data1(rename=(name=country)) data2;
by country;
run;
```

The result of this code is the data sets just being stacked on top of one another. My goal is to attach the continent to the country, ie identify the continent of each country.

```
data1:

Continent    Name
Asia         China
Australia    New Zealand
Europe       France

data2:

Country         Var    City
China           1.2    Beijing, China
New Zealand     3.5    Auckland, New Zealand
France          2.8    Paris, France

data I want:

Country         Var    City                    Continent
China           1.2    Beijing, China          Asia
New Zealand     3.5    Auckland, New Zealand   Australia
France          2.8    Paris, France           Europe

data I get:

Country         Var    City                     Continent
China           1.2    Beijing, China          
New Zealand     3.5    Auckland, New Zealand   
France          2.8    Paris, France           
China                                           Asia
New Zealand                                     Australia
France                                          Europe
```

Comment: Which dataset has the variable CONTINENT?  It should not be in both.  Show examples of somes values of COUNTRY and NAME that your think should match but SAS is not matching.  Is the case the same? Does one have leading spaces? Other invisible characters?

Comment: Only ONE data set has the variable continent. I have updated my question to show an example of my data sets.

Answer (score 1):

From my example data your logic works for me. Maybe your error has to do with your `length` statement

```
Data Df1;
    INPUT Country $1-18 @19 Temp;
    datalines;
    United States 87
    Canada        68
    Mexico        88
    Russia        77
    China         55
    ;
Run;

Data Df2;
    INPUT name $1-18 @19 season $;
    datalines;
    United States Summer
    Canada        Summer
    Mexico        Summer
    Russia        Winter
    China         Winter
    ;
Run;


Proc sort data=Df1;
    by Country;
Proc sort data= Df2;
    by Name;
Run;

Data Merged_data;
    merge Df1 Df2(rename=(name=country));
    by country;
Run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the values of the variables are what you think they are. Print the values using $QUOTE. format.  Look at the results using fixed length font.  etc.

Perhaps one has the actual values you see and the other has a code that is decoded by a format to the values you see.

If it is not an issue of formatted value versus actual value then perhaps the records in DATA2 have leading spaces.

This program produces the result you are showing.  If you remove the leading spaces from COUNTRY in DATA2 then the merge works as expected.

```
data data1 ;
  input Continent $13. Name $15.;
cards;
Asia         China
Australia    New Zealand
Europe       France
;

data data2;
  input Country $15. Var City $25.;
  country=' '||country;
cards;
China           1.2    Beijing, China
New Zealand     3.5    Auckland, New Zealand
France          2.8    Paris, France
;

proc sort data=data1; by name; run;
proc sort data=data2; by country; run;

data want ;
 merge data2 data1(rename=(name=country)) ;
 by country;
run;
```

Results:

```
Obs    Country         Var    City                     Continent

 1      China          1.2    Beijing, China
 2      France         2.8    Paris, France
 3      New Zealand    3.5    Auckland, New Zealand
 4     China            .                              Asia
 5     France           .                              Europe
 6     New Zealand      .                              Australia
```